# Selenium when clicking Login button getting an error via code

Tags: selenium

I am performing the following action:

login into a site ...
when I click via my code the 'Login' button I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <button class="md-raised md-primary hvr-bounce-to-top eq-button big-btn login-btn md-button md-ink-ripple" ng-transclude="" style="background-color: #01759f;" type="submit" log-click="" ng-click="submitted=true">...</button> is not clickable at point (865, 952). Other element would receive the click: <form name="myForm" ng-submit="login()" id="my-form" style="height: 100%;" class="layout-align-center-center layout-column ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required">...</form>
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.96)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 51 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-773M6OU', ip: '10.0.0.63', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233), userDataDir=C:\Users\Erez\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir7656_25308}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=58.0.3029.96, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: acad3629efc60ea6422f7ef108a2bde2
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:272)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:82)
    at testproject.testclass.main(testclass.java:23)
```

and this is my code:

```
public class testclass {
    static WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    //static WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //  System.out.println("Hello");
         driver.get("http://192.168.191.41:9000/#/login");
         driver.findElement(By.id("input_0")).sendKeys("equlaum");
         driver.findElement(By.id("input_1")).sendKeys("equlaum");
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();
    }

}
```

I cannot sign in to the site ... any idea how to solve it?

thanks!

Comment: as the said button is Angular JS component; you can add some explicit wait for that element to be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is pretty clear from the error stack trace as it reads `button is not clickable at point (865, 952). Other element would receive the click`

The possible reason can be:

1. Either the `xpath` you provided is not unique. You need to find a unique xpath with the help of dev tools.
2. The `submit` button doesn't have a `id` or a `name` but it contains a lot of classes, so we may need to slow down a bit by inducing some `ImplicitlyWait` before clicking the `submit` button.
3. Other way round, as the error is `button is not clickable`, you may induce an `ExplicitWait` for the `submit` button to be clickable as follows:

   ```
   WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15); 
       wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']"))); 
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();
   ```

PS: As you are able to do the following:

```
     driver.findElement(By.id("input_0")).sendKeys("equlaum");
     driver.findElement(By.id("input_1")).sendKeys("equlaum");
```

I don't feel they are within a frame either.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it did not work out , I tried to do the following:
driver.findElement(By.className("md-raised md-primary hvr-bounce-to-top eq-button big-btn login-btn md-button md-ink-ripple")).click();

This is my selector: 
<button class="md-raised md-primary hvr-bounce-to-top eq-button big-btn login-btn md-button md-ink-ripple" ng-transclude="" style="background-color: #01759f;" type="submit" log-click="" ng-click="submitted=true"><span class="ng-scope">Login</span><div class="md-ripple-container">

and it is inside a 'div'